# Salesforce marketing cloud person account and personalisation in journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, person-accounts

I need help with personalisation from person account in journey builder.
I have created the field in profile management and mapped it to the person account field.
I have a total of 3 fields. The personalisation works if I send an email to a sfdc report via user unitiated send.
If I use a journey entry source person contact updated it doesn’t populate the personalisation.

I’ve also tried to create some ampscript and do a lookup but doesn’t work in the journey and in the email preview only works for certain records

Comment: Are you able to share the AMPscript code that you've tried?

Comment: Hi Eliot, I've solved it doing an ampscript lookup to a sync Data extension. Not sure why the basic personalisation would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Basic personalization in journey builder is based on journey data, meaning the data extension created for your entry event. Those fields look very different from typical personalization strings or synchronized data.

I explained it in an earlier thread, where it even is the same scenario (Person Accounts), so you should be able to work on with the code and concept explained there:
[Question about AMPScript in Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225504/using-salesforce-fields-to-render-amp-script-variables-in-journey-emails-sf-dat/)